# Facebook like button integrating in django template

Tags: django, facebook, python-2.7, django-templates

I'm trying to put like button on my web page using this code

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={{request.build_absolute_uri}}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true">
    </iframe>
<style>.fbook{position: absolute; font-color:#ddd; top:-1668px; font-size:10;}</style>
                </style>
<a href="http://www.druckerverwaltung.de‎" class="fbook">Immer neue Informationen...</a> 
<a href="http://www.videobeamer24.de" class="fbook">Eine neue Bestenliste im Netz</a> 
<a href="http://www.howtoaddlikebutton.com" class="fbook">click</a>
<style>.fbook-style_map:initreaction=10false_attempt10-border</style>
<style>closemap"init"if=fb_connect-start="25"check_bandwith</style>
```

but in first line I want current page's url dynamically in django template so I used         `{{request.build_absolute_uri}}`   but it didn't work, though there was no error but its not showing like button.

is it correct template tag or I have to do something else?

Comment: Do you have the requests midddlewear jnstalled?

Answer (score 0):

Pass this variable from view to template,

```
full_url = request.build_absolute_uri(None)

# pass full_url into the template context.
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri

Comment: can we do it without rendering from a view?
I mean directly put this `request.build_absolute_uri` tag in django template or similar approach.